# How do I make a function take longer in Python?

Tags: python

For an assignment from the professor, he's given us code that works fine, but wants us to 'downgrade' it so it will take longer on two particular functions. We're working with a given array of:

```
array = ["apples", "bananas", "cucumbers", "dates", "elderberries"]
```

and four functions given by the professor. The two he wants to take longer are the insert and delete functions.

```
def insertArray():
    print("Inserting figs into array at index 2")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array.insert(2,"figs")
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Insert elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))


def deleteArray():
    print("Deleting bananas at index 1 from array")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array.pop("bananas")
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Delete elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))
```

And I know that the array.insert and array.pop need to be replaced, but I have no clue what process or way I can go to achieve the same result, but make it take longer. Does anyone have a suggestion for what I can do?

Comment: `array.pop("bananas")` doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: just a very weird requirement needing to slowdown a function...

Comment: Yeah, this is the first time I've ever heard of an assignment asking to downgrade something. And it's also why I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: Have you tried using `array = array[:2] + ["figs"] + array[2:]` for insert

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same thing without the native list functions. Except I used `array.pop(1)` insted of `array.pop("bananas")` since it makes no sense.

```
array = ["apples", "bananas", "cucumbers", "dates", "elderberries"]


def insertArray():
    print("Inserting figs into array at index 2")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array = array[:2] + ["figs"] + array[2:]
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Insert elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))


def deleteArray():
    print("Deleting bananas at index 1 from array")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array = array[:1] + array[2:]
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Delete elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))
```

Comment: When I try to implement what you have done, I get hit with "local variable 'array' referenced before assignment".

Specifically, on the first print(array) of both the insert and delete functions.

Comment: Yeah I assumed you had the `array = ["apples", "bananas", "cucumbers", "dates", "elderberries"]`defined before executing the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.sleep()` to delay a function by the specified number of seconds.

```py
import time

def insertArray():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Inserting figs into array at index 2")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array.insert(2,"figs")
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Insert elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))


def deleteArray():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Deleting bananas at index 1 from array")
    print(array)
    start = timer()
    array.pop()
    end = timer()
    print(array)
    print("Delete elapsed time = {0:.8f}".format(end - start))
```

(Redefine `pop` and `insert` functions)

```py
def pop(iterable, index=-1):
    a = iterable[index]
    del iterable[index]
    return a
```

and

```py
def insert(iterable, index, item):
    iterable = iterable[index-1:] + item + iterable[:index-1]
```

Comment: While the thought is appreciated, the professor has us doing this because he wants us to find a way to manually do what the .insert and .pop functions, meaning we do what those two do, but manually.